# How can I create a summary count of the number of common unique values across two data frames?

Tags: r

I am creating a summary table and am running into some trouble identifying common (character) values between two data frames.

I have two data frames, `df1` and `df2`, and want to know how many unique ID values from `df1$id` appear in `df2$id`.

I am aware that I can do this:

```
df1$id %in% df2$id
```

This will return something like this:

```
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  [23] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

I am aware that I could also run this:

```
table(df1$id %in% df2$in)
```

Which returns this:

```
FALSE   TRUE
57452 196269
```

However, these approaches don't work as expected when creating a column in a summary table as I want a single figure which counts the number of `TRUE` matches but I only get either errors or other unwanted results.

This is my current incorrect approach, with other/unrelated columns redacted (I have added `count` here despite it being wrong so that I can give an idea of what I hope to achieve):

```
output <-
  data.frame(
    idMatch = count(df1$id %in% df2$id)
  )
```

How can I achieve this?  Is there a simpler approach that I can take?

Comment: Are you looking for `sum(df1$id %in% df2$id)` ?

Comment: Do you mean `length(intersect(x, y))`?

Comment: Thank you for the comments; both of these approaches work well. Is there a way to extract unique values only? I know that using `unique` before each variable is one approach, but is there another way that might be more efficient?